# Mongrel failing to start after an OS update

Tags: centos, apache-2.2, ruby

So there's this installation on a virtual server, administered by Plesk, running CentOS. The OS has been automatically updated recently - this broke a custom ruby installation. I haven't set up the original thing and am not familiar with ruby, therefore I am somewhat at a loss as to what exactly broke.

Via the package manager I made sure that ruby, and gems that were specified, are installed. I copied the original ruby folder back into the /var/www/vhost/ folder where it used to be. In there, the httpdocs folder has a soft link to the rails/servername/public folder.

So technically the website content should be as before. But the ruby/mongrel logs don't even update.

When I visit the site, Apache throws a 503 - Service Temporarily Unavailable error. The error_log is the only thing that's updating, and this is what it contains after a restart:

```
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:30 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:30 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `plesk' does NOT match server name!?
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:30 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `plesk' does NOT match server name!?
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:30 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `plesk' does NOT match server name!?
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:30 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:30 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:30 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:30 2013] [notice] mod_bw : Memory Allocated 0 bytes (each conf takes 32 bytes)
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:30 2013] [notice] mod_bw : Version 0.8 - Initialized [0 Confs]
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:31 2013] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 50 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:31 2013] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp 
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:31 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `plesk' does NOT match server name!?
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:31 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `plesk' does NOT match server name!?
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:31 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `plesk' does NOT match server name!?
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:31 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Apr 21 06:18:31 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.6.6 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

When I try to start mongrel_rails, I see this:

```
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gem_plugin-0.2.3/lib/gem_plugin.rb:109:in `load': uninitialized constant Gem::SourceIndex (NameError)
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:278
from /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:23
```

Comment: To you have gems installed?  Can you do a 'bundle install' in your rails dir?